# Can I do incremental authorization in Gsuite marketplace addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I read about [incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth), where a web app can request minimal scope during sign in and ask for more as the user wants more functionality. Is this possible in addon? Instead of statically defining it in the manifest file, can it be programmatically added as users use the addon?

If I omit some scopes in the manifest file, there would be a mismatch between
the OAuth Consent screen and the OAuth Scopes in the App Configuration for the Marketplace. Will this cause the addon to be shown as unverified to the users?

Comment: Why would you want to implement this in an AddOn? What is your AddOn type (Calendar, Docs, Sheets, Gmail, etc)?

Comment: Its a Google Forms editor addon. Initially, I want to get access to the current form. For advanced users, I want to get access to its spreadsheet along with offline access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment of this answer incremental authorization cannot be implemented for Google Workspace Add-Ons. [In this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#incrementalAuth) you can check which type of apps can use incremental authorization at the moment.

If you want to request this feature for Google Workspace Add-Ons you can do it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206).